# Take the first objects with unique IDs from an array and put them in new list

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am making a dropdown from json file containing array of objects, the problem is some of the objects have same IDs, and I want to extract only the first objects with unique ID (for example 1, then take the second object with unique ID 2 etc..) and put them in a list. That is, I need a list with unique IDs only.

What I have tried so far:

```
var distinctId = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var id = data[i]["id"];
            if (distinctId[id] == undefined) {
                distinctId[id] = [];
            }
            distinctId[id].push(data[i]);
            console.log(data[i]);
        }
```

The json file looks something like this:

```
[
{
id: 1,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
{
id: 1,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
{
id: 2,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
{
id: 2,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
{
id: 3,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
{
id: 3,
field1: ...,
field2: ...
},
]
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried and tell what is not working in your code.

Comment: @maximelian1986 Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce your array, and check if there is an element that matches your criteria:

```
your_json_array.reduce((destArray, obj) => {
    if (destArray.findIndex(i => i.id === obj.id) < 0) {
      return destArray.concat(obj);
    } else {
      return destArray;
    }
  }, []);
```

That will give you another array with the desired data.

Answer (score 2):

If all you wish to do is get the first two unique `id`s of your objects you can do this by mapping your array to an array of id's using `.map` and [destructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

Once you have done this you can use a set to remove all the duplicate's from the array. Lastly, you can use `.splice` to keep the first 2 unique `id`s from your array:

```js
const arr = [{id:1,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'},{id:1,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'},{id:2,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'},{id:2,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'},{id:3,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'},{id:3,field1:'foo',field2:'bar'}],

res = [...new Set(arr.map(({id}) => id))].splice(0, 2);
console.log(res);
```

If you wish to have an array of objects which are unique you can use `.reduce` to create a new array. Essentially the new array is created by adding the first object from the array into it, then checking if the next object has the same `id` as that object. To do this we use `.every`. If it does have the same `id` we go to the next object, if the `id` is different then we can add this to our array. Then when we look at our next object we check if it matches any of the now 2 object id's in our array, if it doesn't we can add it and so on.

```js
const arr = [{id:1,field1:'foo1',field2:'bar1'},{id:1,field1:'foo2',field2:'bar2'},{id:2,field1:'foo3',field2:'bar3'},{id:2,field1:'foo4',field2:'bar4'},{id:3,field1:'foo5',field2:'bar5'},{id:3,field1:'foo6',field2:'bar6'}],

res = arr.splice(1).reduce((acc, elem) => acc.every(({id}) => id != elem.id) ? [...acc, elem] : acc, [arr[0]]);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: The second solution returns only the first object of the array..?

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden The second solution returns an array of 3 objects. The first object with the `id` of 1, the second object with the next unique `id` of 2 and the third object with the unique `id` of 3

Comment: Yes, i got that, thank you btw. But in my array I have maybe 80 unique IDs, and this code returns only one...

Comment: I don't quiet understand what you mean by "only one". The array being return has _3_ objects in it, which has the first occurance of the `id`. Is this not what you were after?

Comment: Instead of printing all of the unique IDs, it returns only the first unique ID. It does not display the other 79.

Comment: @DevShieldMaiden could you provide all your JSON in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using something along the lines of this, however it *may* be a better idea to do what I've done in my second example. Within the second example, you can see that it's storing a list of **all** duplicated ID's, the first example will only work for an even number of duplicated ID's... I.E. if there were three objects with the `id` property set to a value of `1`, you'd still get the value `1` within the `array`variable.

I mean there are other ways in which you could achieve this, you could use a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function in there somewhere, etc. If you require more documentation on how to use the `reduce` function, I'd suggest the [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Finally with example 3, that's simply removing all duplicates, making use of more modern syntax and features such as [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

### Example 1

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,a:'x'},{id:1,a:'x'},{id:2,a:'x'},{id:3,a:'x'}];
var array = objects.reduce((a, i) => {
  a.indexOf(i.id) == -1 ? a.push(i.id) : a.splice(a.indexOf(i.id), 1);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(array);
```

### Example 2

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,a:'x'},{id:1,a:'x'},{id:2,a:'x'},{id:3,a:'x'}];

var array = objects.reduce((a, i) => {
  objects.filter(e => e.id == i.id).length == 1 ?  a.push(i.id) : null; 
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(array);
```

### Example 3

```js
const objects = [{id: 1,a:'x'},{id:1,a:'x'},{id:2,a:'x'},{id:3,a:'x'}];

const removeDuplicates = ([...o]) => o.reduce((a, i) => { 
  a.indexOf(i.id) == -1 ? a.push(i) : null; 
  return a
}, []);

console.log(removeDuplicates(objects));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** To remove duplicates from the original array you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) in conjunction with the optional argument that is passed as `this` to the filtering method.

**2)** To get an array with unique `ids` you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on the previous result.

This is shown on next example:

```js
const input = [
    {id: 1, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
    {id: 1, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
    {id: 2, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
    {id: 2, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
    {id: 3, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
    {id: 3, field1: "f1", field2: "f2"},
];

// Remove duplicates elements.

let res = input.filter(
    function({id}) {return !this.has(id) && this.add(id)},
    new Set()
);

console.log("No duplicates:", res);

// Get a map with only the IDs.

let ids = res.map(({id}) => id);
console.log("Ids:", ids);
```